# Hackerrank Quest -- bug or misunderstanding?

Tags: python

I was playing with Hackerrank and came across [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-quest-1).

It is written as:

> You are given a positive integer N. You have to print a numerical
>   triangle of height N−1 as shown below:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
......
```

My immediate thought was this solution:

```
for i in range(1,input()):
    print(str(i)*i)
```

Which outputs this given (5) as the first line of input:

```
1
22
333
4444
```

The submission says it's not right.  Other suggestions that were accepted are much less elegant in my mind:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print((10**i)//9*i)
```

This outputs:

```
1
22
333
4444
```

The output is identical but the code is ugly.  Why is this solution acceptable and not mine?

Comment: Does yours work for `i` greater than 10?

Comment: `Note Using anything related to strings will give a score of 0.`

Comment: The probem says you can't be using anything related to string, hence the 0 score.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You missed something in the description:

> **Note** Using anything related to strings will give a score of 0.

You are using `str()` in your solution, so it is invalid according to the rules of the challenge. The point is to find that trick with calculating the number rather than build it from a string.

I used:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print(i * (10 ** i - 1) // 9)
```

to pass the challenge, which is fundamentally the same approach. You make use of the fact that 10 // 9 is 1, 100 // 9 is 11, 1000 // 9 is 111, etc.; get yourself enough zeros to produce the right number of digits, and multiply the repeating `1` number with `i` to get a number of repeated `i` digits.